# ReactJS rendering data that is passed from a laravel controller as json string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, controller, laravel-7

I'm totally new to React.

i want to retrive data from a database using laravel ;

in my controller, I receive the data and send it in json form like this

```
public function index()
{
    $data =  DB::table('posts')->get();
    return view('welcome')->withData(json_encode($data));
}
```

and its working perfectly.

Inside my home view, i called react like this.

```
        <div id="example" data="{{ $data }}"></div>
        <script src="js/app.js" ></script>
```

and this is the Example.js :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    export default class Example extends Component
    {
        constructor(props)
        {
            super(props);

            console.log(props.data);//[{"id":1,"name":"Laravel","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":2,"name":"Reacts Js","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

            const json = JSON.parse(props.data);

            var L = json.length;//2
            for(var i =0 ; i < L ; i++)
            {
                console.log(json[i].name);//i==0 : Laravel
                                        // i==1 : Reacts Js
            }
        }

        render()
        {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row justify-content-center">
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-header">Example Component</div>
                                for(var i =0 ; i < L ; i++)
                                {
                                    <div>{json[i].name}</div>
                                }
                                <div className="card-body">I'm an example component!</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>        
            );
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById('example')) {
        var data = document.getElementById(('example')).getAttribute('data');
        ReactDOM.render(<Example data={data}/>, document.getElementById('example'));
    }
```

in the browsers console i can see json[i].name perfectly ! BUT in the  component i have this problem with the followinf error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because JSON is within the scope of `constructor` and is not visible outside of it.
You would want to store the data in the component state and user that in render.

You can use then [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to iterate the JSON data in `render()`.

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(props.data);//[{"id":1,"name":"Laravel","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":2,"name":"Reacts Js","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

    this.state = {
      json:JSON.parse(props.data)
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-md-8">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-header">Example Component</div>
              {this.state.json.map(i => (
                <div>{i.name}</div>
              ))}
              <div className="card-body">I'm an example component!</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is [ReactJS's explanation on state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)